# Use codeiginiter and ajax following the rules codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm struggeling to use codeigniter the way it was created. I'm opening an edit page (order). I want to change data on the page which will be dynamically saved after leaving a field. But when I'm not succeeding in the way codeigniter works or with other words on a "nice way". I don't want to be depending on the uri structure and get the data with uri segment, like the code is now. I want to improve the code beneath but i'm not succeeding...

This is the code to open my view

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {
    // Fetch a page or set a new one
    $this->load->model('shop_m');
    $this->load->model('details_m');
    $this->data['subtitle'] = 'incoming';
    if ($id) {
        if($this->transfer_m->get_permission($id) > 0){      
            $this->data['transfer'] = $this->transfer_m->get_rec($id);
            // $this->data['transfer'] = $this->transfer_m->get($id,true);
            count($this->data['transfer']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'page could not be found';
            $this->data['details'] = $this->details_m->get_by(array('doc_no' => $id),FALSE);
        }
        else{  
            redirect('admin/Dashboard', 'refresh');
        }
    } else {
        $this->data['transfer'] = $this->transfer_m->get_new();
    }

    $this->data['shop_from'] = $this->shop_m->get($this->data['transfer']->from_customer,TRUE);
    $this->data['shop_to'] = $this->shop_m->get($this->data['transfer']->to_customer,TRUE);

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'pages/details/transfer_edit';
    $this->load->view('pages/main', $this->data);

}
```

My ajax call

```
function add_shop(shop){
var id = $('#doc_no').text();

$.ajax({
    url: base_url+"/admin/transfer/add_shop/"+id+"/"+shop,
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-content-container').hide();
    }
})
```

}

my controller function to add a shop

```
    public function add_shop($id){
    $data = array('to_customer' => $this->uri->segment(5));   
    $this->transfer_m->save($data,$id);

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use post. Modify your ajax call and pass the data like below. See the document here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
 data: { id: id, shop: shop }
```

This data can be accessed `$this->input->post('id'); $this->input->post('shop');`